# How do you disable HTML5 in any browser?

Tags: browser

I want to test what happens when a non-html5 browser encounters the Footer tag.  Is there anyway I can disable HTML5 in Chrome, Firefox or IE/Edge?  All the questions that I've seen on the web relate to specific areas such as HTML5 Media, I'm after the whole of HTML5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your page will pretty much look broken without html5

Answer (score 0):

> I want to test what happens when a non-html5 browser encounters the Footer tag

It depends on the browser.

IE 4 and Netscape 4 would behave differently.

> Is there anyway I can disable HTML5 in Chrome, Firefox or IE/Edge?

No. HTML 5 is not "a feature", it is the latest version of the specification. Browsers implement it at their cores, not as a layer on top of their HTML 4 support.